# NameError: name 'WebDriverWait' is not defined

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a Python code written by a frined which actually worked perfectly just a few weeks ago and now is causing some problems.
The code takes a google images search link from a csv file and using Selenium Webdriver (Chrome), gives back a link to the first image on the search page.

What could be the reason for this error? (NameError: name 'WebDriverWait' is not defined)

Thank!

Comment: Could you please show your code (no screenshots of it, just copy and paste it here ^^)

Comment: where is your code ? where is full error message ?

Answer (score 11):

That error typically means you are missing this import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Answer (score 6):

**Import two things:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).